# Button possibly not initialized in Android Fragment

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-fragments, android-activity

I have been following a tutorial on implementing crud functionality in an android app.

Following the guide the submit button should be adding a character to my Firebase RTB, the app is compiling but nothing is happening when I hit submit, previous work I have done I have always initialized buttons but when I try to do that here I can't use `findViewById(R.id.submit)` as the `findViewById` throws an unresolved reference error, if I don't declare that part then it crashes as expected due to not being initialized. In the tutorial I am following the button is also not initialized but the code works as expected.

I believe that the button is not registering being clicked but I am not fully sure as to why its not working.

Here is my code

```
class CreatePlayerFragment: Fragment() {

    private lateinit var viewModel: CharacterViewModel
    private lateinit var submit: Button

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View?{

        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(CharacterViewModel::class.java)
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_create_player, container, false)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        submit = clearFindViewById(R.id.submit)

    }


    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)



        viewModel.result.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
           val message = if(it == null) {
                getString(R.string.character_added)
            } else {
                getString(R.string.character_failure, it.message)
           }
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        })

        //listener for submission button
        submit.setOnClickListener {
            val name: String = editTextPlayerName.text.toString().trim()
            val race: String = editTextRace.text.toString().trim()
            val classType: String = editTextClass.text.toString().trim()
            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) {

                input_layout_name.error = getString(R.string.field_required_error)
                return@setOnClickListener
            }

            val character = CharacterModel()
            character.name = name
            character.race = race
            character.classType = classType
            viewModel.addCharacter(character)

        }
    }
}
```

EDIT

So I added in ankolistener on the class to see if the button is registering being clicked and discovered it is, I created logic for a second button to clear the text fields in the fragment and this works as expected, so my problem is the data is simply not being submitted to my Firebase Real Time Database.
This it the code for my CharacterViewModel. I'm using the Android Studio Plugin to link Firebase RTB with this application. I am not getting any errors when I click the submit button to create a character.

```
class CharacterViewModel : ViewModel() {

private val _result = MutableLiveData<Exception?>()
val result: LiveData<Exception?>
    get() = _result

/*
    Add character to DB, save a character under the characters node in the DB with a
    unique key id.

 */
fun addCharacter(character: CharacterModel) {
    val dbCharacterModels = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(NODE_CHARACTERS)
    character.id = dbCharacterModels.push().key
    dbCharacterModels.child(character.id!!).setValue(character).addOnCompleteListener {
        if(it.isSuccessful){
            _result.value = null
        } else {
            _result.value = it.exception
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: check if the tutorial is using data-binding.

Answer (score 0):

You should always initialize views in `onViewCreated()`. This lifecycle method ensures that the fragment and the activity has been rendered on the screen and you can access all the views inside the fragment. `onCreate()` is called before the screen get rendered hence the button is not getting initialized.

Comment: ok, so to fix my problem should I declare an ònViewCreated` function and move the code from the ònActivityCreated` function into that?

Comment: you are currently initializing button in oncreate, place that in onViewCreated. onActivityCreated works fine too.

Answer (score 0):

The **findViewById** does work in the *Fragment*. However, you can't just call this method. First, you to wait till the view is created. This can be done within **onViewCreated** method. Within this method, you can use this method to find the object: **getView().findViewById**

Comment: Hi I'm not sure if I follow you fully but I attempted something else, so I moved all the code inside the `onActivityCreated` to be inside  `onViewCreated` instead

I then also added this line of code to try initialize the button 
`submit = getView().findViewById(R.id.submit)`

I am getting this error however

``Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type View``

Comment: This error might arise when calling a method that is @Nullable. To avoid this you need to check if the object is null before doing any further actions with that object. This is a Kotlin issue and not java. Hence, a simple **if** check should fix your issue.